# "list_or_dict must be a list or a dict" when using append in openpyxl package of Python

Tags: python, range, canopy, openpyxl

Based on this tutorial : [LINK](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) we have this structure:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in range(1,3):
    ws.append(range(100))

wb.save(finename ='mtest2.xlsx')
```

This returns below error for `ws.append(range(100))`:

```
TypeError: list_or_dict must be a list or a dict
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Which part don't you understand? Presumably you're using Python 3.x, where [`range` doesn't return a `list`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists), hence the message you're being given. Try `list(range(100))`.

Comment: Thank you. please add your answer.

Comment: @CharlieClark looking at [the documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html?highlight=append#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.append), it even notes that *iterable* includes *range*, but then finally adds that this would be a `TypeError`. In fact the [source code](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.html#Worksheet.append) seems to handle `range`, so now I'm confused - is this a different version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidently the argument to `ws.append` must be either a dictionary or a list. Presumably you're using Python 3.x, where [`range` no longer returns a list](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#views-and-iterators-instead-of-lists) (it now behaves like Python 2.x's `xrange`).

The simplest fix is to explicitly convert the `range` into a `list`:

```
for row in range(1, 3):
    ws.append(list(range(100)))
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but `range(1,3)` doesn't work! for every value of first element of range, it starts from first row. Why!?

Comment: @user2991243 from the code provided, I can't tell. You're not actually using `row` in the example, so it might as well read `for _ in range(2):`. Note that indices in Python are zero-based, that might be something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

As @jonrsharpe notes, you cannot use range like this. A range in Python is essentially for looping over only. You can convert it to a list: `list(range(100))` if you really need the values explicitly.

Comment: "A range in Python is essentially for looping over only." True-ish in Python 3, not in Python 2, where the range function returns an actual list object.